# definition of lie bracket of linear connection and a $\operatorname{End}(E)$-valued $k$-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, characteristic-classes

I'm currently studying LECTURES ON CHERN-WElL THEORY, in which it defines the trace function on a vector bundle $(M,E)$ by setting
$$ \operatorname{tr}(\omega\otimes A) = (\operatorname{tr}A)\omega ,\quad A\in \operatorname{End}(E),\omega \in \mathcal{A}^*(M) $$

but lemma 1.7 said for all $A\in \mathcal{A}^*(M;\operatorname{End}(E))$ and linear connection $\nabla$ on $E$,
$$  d\operatorname{tr}A= \operatorname{tr}[\nabla,A] $$

holds.

What confused me is that in the book the lie bracket of $\operatorname{End}(E)$-valued forms is defined while $\nabla$ is **NOT** a $\operatorname{End}(E)$-valued $1$-form. So, can anyone explain what is this lie bracket $[\nabla,A]$?

Comment: I guess it's just a compact notation, like $[\nabla,A]X = (\nabla A)X - A\nabla X$. Maybe checking out the proof will help.

Comment: no the proof is totally without formulas and shows no sign of its definition.

Comment: and this lemma requires $[\nabla,A]$ is a $\operatorname{End}(E)
$-valued form i just cant figure it out.

Comment: Why is $\nabla$ not an $\text{End}(E)$-valued $1$-form? $\nabla$ is a linear map from sections of $E$ to $E$-valued $1$-forms, which is an $\text{End}(E)$-valued $1$-form, isn't it?

Comment: cause $\nabla(fX)$ dosent equal $ f\nabla X$, it isn't.

Comment: Yes, of course. I didn’t stop to think.

Comment: You might actually be referring to Lemma 1.8. Anyway, you know from the first part of the proof that, whatever it is, the expression $Tr([\nabla,A])$ will not depend on the choice of connection. I agree with you that the first step in the proof should have been to spell out what the expression means; it seems to me that Didier's interpretation makes sense, you are tracing the operator sending a section $s$ to $\nabla(A(s))-A(\nabla s)$.

Comment: follow-up from the previous comment: assume that we are tracing $s\mapsto \nabla(A(s))-A(\nabla s)$. The expression reads something like $\mathrm{d}A^i_j-\vartheta^i_k\wedge A^k_j+\vartheta^k_j\wedge A^i_k$, where $\vartheta$ is the local representative of the connection. When traced, this will give you $\mathrm{d}A^i_i+0$, as requested.

Comment: Thanks for your views @Johnny Lemmon, I think I get what the author tried to illustrate this lie bracket. He wanted a lie bracket on $\mathcal{A}^*(M;\operatorname{End}(E))$ which can be viewed as an element of $\mathcal{A}^*(M) \otimes \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$. I will state my own view.

Answer (score 1):

I think the auther tried to define a product of two matrixes whose entries are forms and its action on $\Gamma(E)$. In this view the only thing he left is to define the exterior operator on $\mathcal{A}^*(M) \otimes \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})
$ and how it acts on $\Gamma(E)$, since $\nabla=\omega+d$.

If we define this exterior operator(differ from the one on $\mathcal{A}^*(M)$) on $\mathcal{A}^*(M) \otimes \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})
$ by (frame {e_i} of $E$ is already chosen)
$$ dA = d(A^i_j)=(dA^i_j),A\in \mathcal{A}^*(M) \otimes \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R}) ,\quad de=d(x^ie_i)=(dx^1,\cdots,dx^r)^T,e\in\Gamma(E) $$

then the definition fits all the actions I want on $\operatorname{End}(E)$.

Comment: then we have 
$$  \operatorname{tr}[\nabla, A] = \operatorname{tr}[\omega+d, A] = 0 +\operatorname{tr}[d, A] = \operatorname{tr}dA=d\operatorname{tr}A$$

Comment: You should edit your answer rather than comment additional important statements!